# a4j:ajax not fired when leaving the field with mouse

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have an inputText with a nested a4j:ajax call. When I change its value and leave the field using tab, the ajax call is fired. However, if after changing the value I leave the field with the mouse (by clicking in any other field), the ajax call is NOT fired. Why?

I'm using JBoss 6.1.0.Final, Mojarra 2.1.28, RichFaces 4.2.3.Final and java 1.6.0.20.

```
<h:inputText
    id="revenue"
    value="#{myMB.revenue}">
    <f:convertNumber
        type="number"
        minFractionDigits="2"
        maxFractionDigits="2"
        locale="pt_BR" />
    <a4j:ajax
        event="change"
        execute="revenue"
        listener="#{myMB.doSomething}"></a4j:ajax>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: regardless from the order and how many times you try; it works when you press tab, but doesn't work when you click on another component, right?

Comment: did you try using `event="blur"`?